# PMD Apex ExcessiveParameterList Rule error

Tags: apex, security, pmd

When I run the APEX PMD, getting Design Error for the Below method.

`ExcessiveParameterList Avoid long parameter lists.`

Checked below link not able to solve this issue, Can anyone please help me on this.

https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#excessiveparameterlist

```
@AuraEnabled   
    public static boolean updatestudentProgramDiscount(Id recId, string discountType, decimal discountPercentage, string discountDetails) {
       
        try{
            students_Programs__c spt;         
                    spt =[select Id from students_Programs__c where Id=:recId];
                   spt.Discount_Type__c = discountType;
                   spt.Discount__c = discountPercentage;
                   spt.Discount_Details__c = discountDetails;
                   Update spt;  
                   return true;                          
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }      
    }
```

Comment: When I find myself in these situations, I usually create a wrapper class and pass that wrapper class as argument.

Answer (score 5):

As the rule says, you have too many parameters. Consider passing in an entire record:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static updatestudentProgramDiscount(students_programs__c studentRecord) {
    try {
        update studentRecord;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

*Note:* You should use Security.stripInaccessible to prevent invalid field access. Note also using an exception thrown to trigger the "catch"/"error" handler on the client.

Answer (score 4):

From the PMD link mentioned in your question, you can see that the `minimum` property value in the rule set `ExcessiveParameterList` is 4 (screenshot below for ref). This means that if any of your apex method has 4 or more input parameters, PMD will display the rule violation error.

[image]

IMO, since the input params in your apex method are of different data types, it is not a big deal (but still not a best practice). You can modify the ruleset minimum value in PMD configuration to 5 to get rid of this error, but that's not a best practice & not recommended.

Instead, modify the apex method as shown below (or similar). There are other ways to do it and this is just one way.

```
@AuraEnabled   
public static boolean updatestudentProgramDiscount(Id recId, string discountData) {   
    try{
        students_Programs__c spt = [SELECT Id FROM students_Programs__c WHERE Id = :recId];
        
        Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(discountData);
        spt.Discount_Type__c = String.valueOf(m.get('discountType'));
        spt.Discount__c = Decimal.valueOf(m.get('discountPercentage'));
        spt.Discount_Details__c = String.valueOf(m.get('discountDetails'));
        Update spt;  
        return true;                          
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }      
}
```

In the Aura or LWC code, pass the value for `discountData` in string format as shown below:

```
// Replace appropriate values in the JS code
for var discountData = '{"discountType":"", "discountPercentage":"", "discountDetails":""}';
```

Also, try and bulkify the apex method, if possible.